# Image doesn't load - DATA-LAZY

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to load an image using **bloginfo('template_directory')**

My code:

```
<img class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 500px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/home-image.png" />
```

The **assets** folder is inside my theme folder.

**It works perfectly in my localhost**.

But when I upload the code to my server I doesn't show the image.

When I inspect the element, here what it shows:

```
<img class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 500px" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E" data-lazy-src="https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/home-image.png">
```

Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I figured out that **WP Rocket** plugin was the problem. I had to disable the cache for imagens into the settings of that plugin.